# Delete everything which has a certain date

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following sample data set:

```
> dput(head(df, 8))
structure(list(data.founded_at = c("01.06.2012", "26.10.2012", 
"01.04.2011", "01.01.2012", "10.10.2011", "01.01.2007", "01.01.2010", 
"01.01.2011"), data.category_list = c("Entertainment", "Publishing", 
"Electronics", "Software", "Software", "Curated Web", "Software", 
"Analytics")), .Names = c("data.founded_at", "data.category_list"
), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to delete all data which is before a certain date. I tried doing that:

```
df[ df$data.founded_at < "1.1.2012", ]
```

However, I am receiving the whole data set back. Using `str()` on my data frame gives me back:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   33056 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ data.founded_at   : chr  "01.06.2012" "26.10.2012" "01.04.2011" "01.01.2012" ...
 $ data.category_list: chr  "Entertainment" "Publishing" "Electronics" "Software" ...
```

I think the problem might be that my date is a string.

Converting the `data.founded_at` to `Date` gives me only `NA` values in that column:

`df$data.founded_at <- as.Date(as.character(df$data.founded_at),format="%d%m%Y")`

Any ideas how to solve that case?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: The date format you're using is not `%d%m%Y` but `%d.%m.%Y`, change your `as.Date` call accordingly and everything works fine.

Comment: Why downvoting? I see the error now, but haven`t seen it before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string needs the periods.  And, use as.Date in the inequality.

```
df$data.founded_at <- as.Date(as.character(df$data.founded_at),format="%d.%m.%Y")
df[ df$data.founded_at < as.Date("2012-01-01"), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following might work.

```
df$data.founded_at <- strptime(df$data.founded_at, format="%d.%m.%Y", tz="GMT")
df[!df$data.founded_at < as.POSIXlt("2012-01-01"), ]

  data.founded_at data.category_list
1      2012-06-01      Entertainment
2      2012-10-26         Publishing
4      2012-01-01           Software
```